# Associate a name with a number Excel 2007

Tags: excel

Starting at A1 I have a list of 1000s of serial numbers.  In C1 and D1 I have the serial numbers and their associated meaning, respectively.  So A1 contains many repeats of C1.  Is there a way to use a function so that Excel will print out the text from D1 into B1 without having to manually iterate over every single number?

ex.

```
a1.......b1.....c1.....d1
123...blank.....456....text here
123...blank.....123....more text here
123...blank.....255....even more text here
925...blank.....255....etc etc
255...blank.....555....lalal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP should do the trick for you, doing something like this on b1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,C$1:D$5,2,FALSE)
```

and that way you should get something like:

```
A1   B1                 C1       D1
123 more text hrere     456    text here
123 more text hrere     123    more text hrere
123 more text hrere     255    even more text here
925 #N/A                255    etc
225 #N/A                555    lalal
```

This case shows #N/A on 925 and 225 because there's not a matching value on the ones I'm using, and remeber to change the D$5 for D$*wherever your list ends*

Comment: lemme try this out right quick to see if she floats.  thanks.

Comment: sure thing, I hope it helps you

Comment: thanks.  at first it didn't work but that was because the numbers which i was referencing were being stored as text instead of numbers.  as soon as i converted them to numbers then it was all gravy.  thanks, this helped a lot.